# Gps wrong location when connection type network and fused

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, location

I made an android application. we have sample of thousands records some record got correct location but approx 30% user have wrong lat and long.
They all have many places(in wrong towns about 250-1200 km away).
Can anyone tell me where is the problem? Thank you!

Comment: Probably mobile hotspots, if they're used in the location fix they can screw with the results.  You have to assume that location is not accurate-  its usually ok (especially GPS), but will occassionally just be very off (especially on network).  There's no way to fix it, you need to accept and deal with it.